# Bootstrap 3 navbar jumping onto two lines rather than collapsing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Think I'm missing the obvious here, but I have a Bookstrap 3 navbar that works great in desktop view but as I squeeze the width and it gets to tablet size rather than collapsing into the toggle menu it's jumping the menu onto two lines:

http://www.doorsets.org.uk/

I've tried reducing the text size in the navbar via a media query but that isn't solving it.

What am I missing?
Appreciate it.  Thank you.
NJ

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to change the point at which the navbar collapses, you can do this by creating a [customized Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and setting the `@grid-float-breakpoint` to a larger number.

This variable unfortunately also influences the `dt` and `dd` inside a `.dl-horizontal` which might be a problem.

If you want to use a media query to reduce the `font-size` you can use the `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a` selector. It however needs to become `9px` at the smallest viewport size to still stay on a single row which is quite unreadable.

Comment: The value listed in the customized Bootstrap area, for grid-float-breakpoint, is @screen-sm-min.  Do I simply change that to a numerical value to edit?

Comment: I've never customized Bootstrap for this myself, but that's exactly how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar):

> #### Overflowing content
>
> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:
>
> - Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.
> - Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using responsive utility classes.
> - Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable or add your own media query.

It goes on to say:

> #### Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is `768px` (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).